# Setting Backbone model through JSON file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and I'm trying to set a collection of models with data loaded from a json-file. But it won't get set. Whats the problem here? Anyone having an idea? When i fetch the collections it seems that its empty.

JSON

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "media": "",
        "desc": "lorem",
        "img": "ipsum"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "media": "",
        "desc": "lorem",
        "img": "ipsum"
    }
]
```

}

Javscript

```
    var Card = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    defaults: function() {  
        return {  
            items: {
                id: "lorem",  
                media: "lorem",
                desc:"lorem",
                img: "lorem"
            }  
        };  
    },  

    clear: function() {  
        this.destroy();  
    }  
});  

var CardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: Card,  
    url: "file.json",
    parse: function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i<response.items.length; i++) {

        }
    } 
});  

var cards = new CardCollection();
cards.fetch();  
console.log(cards)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch is asynchronous, it returns immediately before the data has been loaded.

Try this

```
var cards = new CardCollection();
cards.fetch({
    success: function () {
        console.log(cards);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct answer to accept. Pls verify the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `CardCollection.parse` method is called with the response. If no transformation is required to the response from the server, you can remove the parse method of the `CardCollection`. The default implementation is pass thru and the response is used as-is.

Basically `parse` should return the array to be added to the collection. The current implementation does not do anything. return is missing for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you! So what i needed to do was basically to add this.

    parse: function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i<response.cards.length; i++) {
            return response.cards;
        }
    }
As said I'm new the backbone and not too familiar with how it works with models and collection. Is the way i have done it now good/bad/good practice you think?

Comment: No..Just remove for loop and `return response.items` from the method as I have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just return something from your parse method and you are good to go. It is expected to return an array of objects and each object will fit into your model. So finally **you will have a collection of models corresponding to array of objects being returned from parse method.**

Try this

```
var CardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
  model: Card,
  url: "file.json",
  parse: function (response) {
    return response.items;
  }
});
```

Read this [Documentation on Parse Method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) for more information.